# Buildroot cross-compile error when gdbserver included - conflicting declaration ‘typedef struct rpl_mbstate_t rpl_mbstate_t’

Tags: compiler-errors, raspberry-pi3, cross-compiling, buildroot

With buildroot-2020.05.1 I get errors as below when gdbserver is included

```
In file included from build-gnulib-gdbserver/import/stdint.h:556,
             from ../common/common-defs.h:66,
             from ../common/common-debug.c:20:
             /home/bcu/work/buildroot-2020.05.1/output/host/arm-buildroot-linux- 
             uclibcgnueabihf/include/c++/9.3.0/cwchar:58:5: 
             error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef struct rpl_mbstate_t rpl_mbstate_t’
             58 |   } mbstate_t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue right now. You have to enable wide characters support for the toolchain in Buildroot config:

1. Run `make nconfig` (or `make menuconfig` if you prefer)
2. Select `Toolchain -> Enable WCHAR support`, save config and exit
3. Clean up previous toolchain build: `make clean`
4. Build everything again: `make -j$(nproc)`

This helped me with Buildroot 2020.02.10 when compiling GCC 5.5.0 & uClibc for ARM32LE. Hope this will help you & other folks from Google too :)